# Do while with User input in C

Tags: c, loops, user-input

I am VERY new to C although I have some background in Java. I basically want a user driven menu where the user picks a number and that number has some command or function. right now I have

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int response = 0;
    while(response != 4){
        printf("Please choose an option!\n");
        printf("1. Check Flight capacity\n");
        printf("2. Check for seat availability\n");
        printf("3. Purchase seats\n");
        printf("4. quit\n");
        scanf("%d", response);
    }
}
```

Which I feel should work, except it crashes after every time I input a number. Any suggestions/ help is greatly appreciated

Comment: &response -- functions in c can't modify their parameters unless they have an address. scanf needs an address to write to. &response is the address of response.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function scanf expects the address of the variable where the result should be written:

```
scanf("%d", &response);
```

You are passing in the variable itself, rather than the address.  Since you initialized `response` to 0, scanf is trying to write the user input to the address 0 rather than to the address of your variable.

Comment: These pointers will be the death of me haha thank you guys. C is strange coming from java.

Comment: Yep.  I started with C, but have been on Java and C# for ages.

Comment: This wouldn't work in java either (primitive types are passed by value)

Comment: @user3704079: I think Matt means if there were a function like `scanf` in Java, that you would also have to pass in the address of the variable rather than the variable itself.  The same is true for C#, you would have to pass it as a reference parameter e.g. `ref response`.